# Поиск строк по заданному слову\букве\цифре

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Есть код для поиска строк:

```
procedure Form4.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var F:TextFile;// Переменной присваивается значение TextFile
Str:string;// Переменной присваивается значение String
begin
  Assign(F,'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
  reset(F);// Открывает текстовый файл для чтения
  while not eof(F) do// Цикл, который перебирает строки 
   begin
      readln(F, Str);// Ввод слова\буквы\цифры для поиска строки
      if pos(textbox1.text, Str)>0 //  есть ли слово\буква\цифра в строке
      then
      textbox2.text:= str; // Вывод строки в текстбокс
   end;
   CloseFile(F);// Закрыть файл
end;
```

Код работает но возникла проблема. Допустим у меня есть в файле такая информация:

```
12345 Максим

67890 Максим
```

При вводе "Максим" мне выдает только посл. строку. А надо все строки в которых есть это слово. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо

```
textbox2.text:= str;
```

написать

```
textbox2.Text:= textbox2.Text + #13#10 + str;
```

Если писать **textbox2.text:= str;**, то вы каждый раз будете затирать прошлую запись в текстбоксе. А когда напишете **textbox2.Text:= textbox2.Text + #13#10 + str;**, то к предыдущей записи будете прибавлять новую. Такая операция сложения строк называется конкатенацией.

---

Гуглите конкатенацию и прочие операции со строками.

Comment: @teanЫЧ о такой операции даже не слышал. Буду знать, спасибо :)